# Using the R Carets packages train function with stochastic classification methods

Tags: r, r-caret

As far as I understand the *train* function from the caret package:

```
model <- train(Class ~ ., data=training, method = "nnet", trControl = train_control)
```

Produces a model by trying a range of parameter values and assessing the produced model on an unseen section of the training data. The Model which performs the best is then returned as the final model.

However many classification methods use stochastic training methods; such as neural networks trained with back propagation.

Therefore trying each set of parameters once during training may not give a good representation of how well those parameters perform.

Is it possible to tell the *train* function to try each set of parameters multiple times and use an average of their performance? If not would it be possible to implement this behaviour using the *train* function?

Edit: I'm not using "repeatedcv" and so cannot simply set set the number of repeats.

This is my train_contol:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = .75, number = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new answer based on the comments in my previous one. You can specify the `index` in `trainControl` which is a list containing indexes for each of the `LGOCV` training samples. By default the indexes not used for training are used for testing. So, you can achieve what you want with:

```
library(caret)

k <- 25L
indexList <- vector("list", k)
names(indexList) <- paste0("TrainIndexes", 1:k)

trainIdx <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
for (i in 1:k) {
    indexList[[i]] <- as.integer(trainIdx)
}

mod <- train(Species ~ ., 
        data = iris, 
        method = "nnet", 
        trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV", index = indexList))
print(mod)

Neural Network 

150 samples
  4 predictors
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Repeated Train/Test Splits Estimated (25 reps, 0.75%) 

Summary of sample sizes: 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  decay  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
  1     0e+00  0.7266667  0.5900000  0.175806490  0.26370973
  1     1e-04  0.8344444  0.7516667  0.177045657  0.26556849
  1     1e-01  0.9722222  0.9583333  0.000000000  0.00000000
  3     0e+00  0.8677778  0.8016667  0.064290205  0.09643531
  3     1e-04  0.8600000  0.7900000  0.044270493  0.06640574
  3     1e-01  0.9166667  0.8750000  0.000000000  0.00000000
  5     0e+00  0.8755556  0.8133333  0.024216105  0.03632416
  5     1e-04  0.8633333  0.7950000  0.007691318  0.01153698
  5     1e-01  0.9166667  0.8750000  0.000000000  0.00000000
```

That is, `train` will use the indexes in `indexList` for each of the cross-validation procedures, and since each element is the same, it will aways be training using the same data. As a test, you can change the `method` to `"rpart"` and see that the SD values are 0 (since it is a deterministic algorithm) Hope this is what you want this time.

Comment: Perfect! The up-most appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `number` in `trainControl` which means that for each set of parameters, the `"LGOCV"` (leave-group-out cross-validation) is performed `number` times. An example:

```
library(caret)

mod <- train(Species ~ ., 
        data = iris, 
        method = "nnet", 
        trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = 0.75,
                number = 10))

print(mod)

Neural Network 

150 samples
  4 predictors
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Repeated Train/Test Splits Estimated (10 reps, 0.75%) 

Summary of sample sizes: 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  decay  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
  1     0e+00  0.7888889  0.6833333  0.30037699   0.45056549
  1     1e-04  0.8027778  0.7041667  0.30944494   0.46416741
  1     1e-01  0.9555556  0.9333333  0.01434438   0.02151657
  3     0e+00  0.8388889  0.7583333  0.17411347   0.26117021
  3     1e-04  0.9500000  0.9250000  0.05037582   0.07556373
  3     1e-01  0.9722222  0.9583333  0.03207501   0.04811252
  5     0e+00  0.9166667  0.8750000  0.11785113   0.17677670
  5     1e-04  0.9583333  0.9375000  0.03000343   0.04500514
  5     1e-01  0.9722222  0.9583333  0.03207501   0.04811252

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final values used for the model were size = 3 and decay = 0.1.
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I'm not using repeatedcv. I'm using a simple holdout method. It's a nice answer though which will hopefully be useful to others.

Comment: In that case can you provide your `train_control`? I think it would help in order to give a good answer.

Comment: `trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = 0.75, number = 10)` should repeat the "leave-group-out cross-validation" 10 times for each set of parameters.

Comment: I think it uses a different data split each time. Maybe its a strange requirement but I don't want it do to that. I want train to try the same set of parameters multiple times using the same data split in order to assess average performance.

Comment: Yes it will split the data differently each time. Any particular reason you don't want this? It should be desirable to split the data differently, in order to see how the parameters perform when tested over the whole dataset, rather than just one randomly chosen split. I *think* I know how to do what you want, though, so will update my answer in a bit.

Comment: I want to compare a range of classification methods with one I am working on. My current set up does what I want the caret package to do. I agree it would be better to use many splits.